# SQL: Nested Query Using 'AND NOT EXISTS' Syntax Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am attempting to create a query that shows me the members who used a service from their account in date range one and then did not use a service from their account in date range two.

I have created the query with a nested query using 'AND NOT EXISTS' but I keep getting an error and I do not know the cause.

```
SELECT        
    SS.memid
FROM
    SS 
INNER JOIN
    SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid 
INNER JOIN
    MEMBERS ON SS.memid = MEMBERS.memid 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid 
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT SS_1.memid
                                FROM SS AS SS_1  
                                INNER JOIN SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid 
                                INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS_1.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid 
                                INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS PRODUCTS_1 ON SS_1.productid = PRODUCTS_1.productid 
                                INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS AS PRODUCTCATS_1 ON PRODUCTS_1.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS_1.productcatid
                                WHERE (SSUSED_1.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2 AND @rvEndWeek2) 
                                  AND (PRODUCTS_1.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47, 68)) 
                                  AND (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite)
                           )
WHERE        
    (SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1) 
    AND (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47, 68)) 
    AND (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite)
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Your error message says that you do not have permission to access a CLR Type that is used as a Parameter.  I'm not sure this has anything to do with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the problem is the main query is not linked to not exists subquery. 
Try it:

create an alias for all table, not on subquery only
join the main query on "where" of the subquery

```
    SELECT        
    SS_0.memid
FROM
    SS SS_0
INNER JOIN
    SSUSED SSUSED_0 ON SS_0.ssid = SSUSED_0.ssid 
INNER JOIN
    MEMBERS MEMBERS_0 ON SS_0.memid = MEMBERS_0.memid 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTS PRODUCTS_0 ON SS_0.productid = PRODUCTS_0.productid 
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTCATS PRODUCTCATS_0 ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid 
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT SS_1.memid
                                FROM SS AS SS_1  
                                INNER JOIN SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid 
                                INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS_1.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid 
                                INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS PRODUCTS_1 ON SS_1.productid = PRODUCTS_1.productid 
                                INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS AS PRODUCTCATS_1 ON PRODUCTS_1.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS_1.productcatid
                                WHERE (SSUSED_1.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2 AND @rvEndWeek2) 
                                  AND (PRODUCTS_1.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47, 68)) 
                                  AND (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite)
                                  AND (SS_0.memid = SS_1.memid) -- Joint main Query and Subquery
                           )
WHERE        
    (SSUSED_0.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1) 
    AND (PRODUCTS_0.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47, 68)) 
    AND (MEMBERS_0.siteid = @rvSite)
```